# fetch not recognized as an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch

When I write this in the console in the devtools:

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/api/products", {
    headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
});
const products = await response.json();
```

I am able to successfully get the data.

But when I run my node project with the same code in a JS file I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Comment: What version of node are you using? (you can find this with `node --version`)

Comment: Do you have [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) installed?

Comment: `v12.18.1`. Tried @3limin4t0r's suggestion but no luck.

Comment: @ciaodejan Did you require the library after installation? If you didn't you still can't use `fetch`. Make sure you have `const fetch = require('node-fetch')` as documented in [Loading and configuring the module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module)

Comment: It's not `fetch` not being recognised, it's the `await` keyword.

Comment: "*When I write this in the console in the devtools*" - where exactly? Which devtools (given you tagged this *node*)? Also try updating your node.js, afaik top-level `await` support is part of v14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` can't be used outside of an `async` function, unless you are on Node 14.3.0+ and using ESM. Wrap the code in a block like `(async () => { /* your code here /* })();` and you should be good to go.